# PyCharm adds double closing parentheses after update, any way to disable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, ide, jetbrains-ide

I know that in Smart Keys you can turn off the closing parentheses all together but in the past I was able to just keep typing or hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> moved outside the parentheses and typing if you were at a character and typed the same character it would move past the character and you could type again to add a second of the same character. Now it adds the first time you type it and moves past on the second.

Example, I want to type:

`print()`

but when I type
`print(` it adds the extra `)` (as it should).

In the past I was able to type `)` and be outside the parentheses however; what I get is this:

`print())`

I can turn off the auto closing (which is where I have it currently) but I miss my auto closing.

Side note, it isn't on insert mode and insert mode isn't what I am looking for.

Update, I have noticed this is only with parentheses. `[]{}""''` all work normally. This happens with or without calling a function.